# Writing unit tests for a react component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, cypress, enzyme

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import "./trade.css";
import tradeActions from "./trade-actions/trade-actions";
import TradeDataSeries from "./TradeDataSeries/TradeDataSeries";
import TradeFilters from "./TradeFilters/TradeFilters";
import SelectedData from "../../components/SelectedData/SelectedData";
import appActions from "../app/actions/actions";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Trade() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // Store Selectors
  const dataseries = useSelector((state) => state.trade.dataseries);
  const facts = useSelector((state) => state.trade.facts);
  const location = useLocation();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (dataseries.length > 0) {
      return;
    }
    dispatch(tradeActions.fetchTradeDataseriesRequest());
    Promise.all([
      dispatch(tradeActions.fetchDatasourceDocumentsRequest()),
      dispatch(tradeActions.fetchCountriesRequest()),
      dispatch(tradeActions.fetchProductsRequest()),
      dispatch(tradeActions.fetchBorderPointsRequest()),
      dispatch(appActions.setDomain(location.pathname.substring(1))),
    ]);
  }, [dispatch, dataseries.length, location]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(tradeActions.setSelectedDataSeries([]));
  }, [dispatch]);
  // Render
  return (
    <>
      <TradeFilters />
      <TradeDataSeries dataSource={dataseries} />
      <SelectedData facts={facts} />
    </>
  );
}
```

I have the above code that I am trying to write a unit test. Below is my test code:

```
import Trade from "./trade";

import renderer from "react-test-renderer";

describe("Trade Commponent Test", () => {
  it("Renders Trade", () => {
    const component = renderer.create(<Trade />);
    expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

But when I run this test coverage `npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false` it shows that this file has no unit test as shown in the attached image:

[image]

I will appreciate it if someone can share a test code snippet to test my code so that I can understand how to write other similar tests.

Other scripts have a better coverage although still not 100%
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are doing well, In your code testcase look fine, but you have  not given proper extension for the testcase file or not define **test** script in package.json file. you need to declare the **test** config.

Following extension used for testcase file:

1. fileName.test.js
2. fileName.test.ts

otherwise you need put testcases file in *test* folder.

I hope you are understand after this you read.

Comment: My testcase file is named like this: `trade.unit.test.js` and the file being tested is `trade.jsx` The test script is defined in package.json as well!

Answer (score -1):

can you rename your file name like this: **trade.test.js**

Comment: The coverage report displays the file being tested, but the file that has test code is named `trade.unit.test.js`